# Find number that can be represented as cube

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Given an integer S. Consider an infinite sequence S, 2S, 3S, ... . Find the first number in this sequence that can be represented as $Q^3$, where Q is some positive integer number.

The number S will be given as a product of N positive integer numbers A1, A2, ..., AN, namely S = A1 * A2 * ... * AN

Example : Let N=2 and array be [2.3] then answer is 216.

How to find it for given N and array A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write down the prime factorization of $S$, and increase the powers of each prime involved to next integer divisible by 3, e.g.
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
6=2^1\times3^1&\longrightarrow2^3\times3^3=216\\
12=2^2\times3^1&\longrightarrow2^3\times3^3=216
\end{split}\end{equation}
Given array $A$, you can factorize $S$ faster. (I am assuming you are writing a program).